# Using EF to connect with existing Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I had a project which contains a Database(SIS.mdf) in its App_Data folder.
Now I have a new MVC4 project. I manually added that database to my new App_Data folder by add existing item option on right click of App_Data folder.
After that I did following things:

1. Create DBcontext for that newly added database

   ```
   public class SisContext : DbContext
   {
       //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       //{
       //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();
       //}
       public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
       public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
       public DbSet<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; set; }
       public DbSet<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }
       public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

       public SisContext():base("SIS")//SIS is name of the database
       {
           if (HttpContext.Current == null)
           {
               Database.SetInitializer<SisContext>(null);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Q1: Is it possible now to interact with the database(SIS) that is in my App_Data folder which exactly contains same and more tables mentioned above?

If yes I have a custom MembershipProvider class which uses the above SisContext class through which I'm trying to validate user

```
public class CodeFirstMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            return false;
        }
        using (var Context = new SisContext())
        {

            AspNetUser User = Context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(Usr => Usr.Username == username);
            if (User == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!User.IsApproved)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (User.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return false;
            }
            String HashedPassword = User.Password;
            Boolean VerificationSucceeded = (HashedPassword != null && Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(HashedPassword, password));
            if (VerificationSucceeded)
            {
                User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0;
                User.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                User.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            else
            {
                int Failures = User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess;
                if (Failures < MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                {
                    User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess += 1;
                    User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
                else if (Failures >= MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                {
                    User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    User.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    User.IsLockedOut = true;
                }
            }
            Context.SaveChanges();
            if (VerificationSucceeded)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my web config I have added my customMembership provider and also have the connection to my SIS database.

When I run i get `model backing the context has changed` error.
Any suggestion to solve my case?

Comment: first question, what do you mean by "added that project to my app_data"? if all that you want from the earlier project is its db, then why not simply add it alone?

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be database not project. Anyways thanks for letting know my error on question

Comment: @Biplov13 follow `Database First` approach, generate classes and you should be good.

Comment: I normally put Database.SetInitializer<SisContext>(null) in Global.asax.cs file under Application_Start(). Don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

pass connectionstring in base.See below

```
public SisContext():base(connectionstring)//SIS is name of the database
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SisContext>(null);
        }
    }
```

right connectionstring should be defined in web.config.